# Is there any way I can use the 'split' on screen keyboard from windows RT on a regular copy of windows 8?

Tags: windows-8

[image]

I noticed that Windows RT supports a rather interesting Tablet-centric on-screen keyboard that 'splits' the keys in two. This might be useful in some circumstances. Is there any way to get this alternate keyboard usable in Windows 8?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to the **Control Panel**, open **Ease of Access Center** and start the **On-Screen Keyboard**.

Right clicking on the title bar allows you to change the lay-out.

[image]

Such that you get a nice shiny Touch Keyboard.

[image]

Try the button in the lower right, which should allow you to split it.

It should also work on the Start Screen and in Modern UI applications.

[image]

Comment: That works perfectly. It has a third 'handwriting' mode as well. Interestingly its not the 'usual' on screen keyboard - the other one has a different set of keys. For one thing the 'standard' OSK dosen't do the 'modal' switch between sets of characters and has a windows key

Answer (score 6):

It sure is! Right click the taskbar, go to Toolbars and click Touch Keyboard. You can then click the bottom-right button to switch layouts. I have found on occasion you need to select the split keyboard twice before it will load.

Also as an interesting side point this is where the handwriting recogniser is now hidden too, useful for those with graphics tablets rather than touchscreens.

Answer (score 0):

Any touch compatible computer, such as the new Lenovo Yoga, will be fully usable with the split keyboard.

I just bought one of these myself and the on screen keyboard works like a champ.